# Laravel split collection method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Problem is how do i print `collection`s into view. and first div only print `Collection 0` and next one `Collection ++` like this

**ExamsController@create**

```
$collections = $questions->split(5);
$collections->toArray();
dd($collections);
```

**dd($collections);**

```
Collection {#455 ▼
#items: array:5 [▼
  0 => Collection {#394 ▶}
  1 => Collection {#619 ▶}
  2 => Collection {#407 ▶}
  3 => Collection {#398 ▶}
  4 => Collection {#275 ▶}
]
}
```

**Create.blade.php**

```
<div>@foreach($collections as $collection)
```

Collection 0

```
 @endforeach</div> 

<div>@foreach($collections as $collection)
```

Collection 1

```
 @endforeach</div> 

<div>@foreach($collections as $collection)
```

Collection 2

```
@endforeach</div>

<div>@foreach($collections as $collection)
```

Collection 3

```
@endforeach</div>

<div>@foreach($collections as $collection)
```

Collection 4

```
@endforeach</div>
```

Comment: Ok, what is the question?

Comment: yeah i forgot it. Was writing sorry. Now check this out please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `index` to fetch particular `collections`

```
@foreach($collections[0] as $collection) //here $collection is Collection 0
```