# laravel split data 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

**Controller**

```
$collections = $questions->split(5);
$collections->toArray();
dd($collections);
```

**dd**

```
Collection {#455 ▼
#items: array:5 [▼
0 => Collection {#394 ▶}
1 => Collection {#619 ▶}
2 => Collection {#407 ▶}
3 => Collection {#398 ▶}
4 => Collection {#275 ▶}
]
}
```

**view**

I'm printing collections in `div` on `View`. Then how to print them by collection by collection.

Problem is how to : print by `collection` by `collection`

Comment: Use index to fetch particular collections

`@foreach($collections[0] as $collection)`

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748416/laravel-split-collection-method/49748532#49748532

Comment: You could explain better what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use index to fetch particular collections

```
@foreach($collections[0] as $collection)
```